# I can't connect my pc's Ethernet to my mobile

Tags: usb-debugging, internet, usb-tethering

I have an ethernet connection in my pc, but the administrator banned it's Wifi connection.
I want to connect my pc's internet through USB, but I don't know how to connect it.
Whenever I use USB tethering, it connects my mobile internet to pc, not my pc's internet to phone.
Finally, if you give simple and understanding guidelines so that I can connect and share my pc's internet to mobile.
yours sincerely

Comment: Please provide specs on your PC, OS, brand and model of you phone and what OS it is running